# How to change the style of an element when we scroll over a particular section of a web?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/dwzqs1vg/

I am trying to change the background color of the element (menu button) when we scroll over the corresponding section of the website just like the website below.

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/

But I am not sure how to set the condition of "when scrolling inside the particular div section".

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if(this.pageYOffset < document.getElementById('firstRow').offsetTop){
        document.getElementById("aboutbutton").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        document.getElementById("archivebutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("projectbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("contactbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('firstRow').offsetTop < this.pageYOffset && this.pageYOffset < document.getElementById('secondRow').offsetTop){
        document.getElementById("aboutbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("archivebutton").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        document.getElementById("projectbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("contactbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('secondRow').offsetTop < this.pageYOffset && this.pageYOffset < document.getElementById('thirdRow').offsetTop){
        document.getElementById("aboutbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("archivebutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("projectbutton").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        document.getElementById("contactbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('thirdRow').offsetTop < this.pageYOffset && this.pageYOffset < document.getElementById('fourthRow').offsetTop){
        document.getElementById("aboutbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("archivebutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("projectbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#333';
        document.getElementById("contactbutton").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    }

})
```

What I've tried so far is above, but the style changes before I even get inside the corresponding row. What am I missing?

PS. I am trying NOT to use jquery and other JS libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current `JavaScript` code with following one. I cleaned it up a little bit by removing code duplication and simplifying the conditions. One thing you have to remember is you have to adjust your `OFFSET` according to the top header navigation bar. You can play with the `OFFSET` and adjust it for the best viewing experience.

```
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

function changeColor(aboutbutton, archivebutton, projectbutton, contactbutton) {
  document.getElementById("aboutbutton").style.backgroundColor = aboutbutton;
  document.getElementById("archivebutton").style.backgroundColor = archivebutton;
  document.getElementById("projectbutton").style.backgroundColor = projectbutton;
  document.getElementById("contactbutton").style.backgroundColor = contactbutton;
}

changeColor('gray', '#333', '#333', '#333');

var OFFSET = 90;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

  if (this.pageYOffset > document.getElementById('fourthRow').offsetTop - OFFSET) {
    changeColor('#333', '#333', '#333', 'gray');
  } else if (this.pageYOffset > document.getElementById('thirdRow').offsetTop - OFFSET) {
    changeColor('#333', '#333', 'gray', '#333');
  } else if (this.pageYOffset > document.getElementById('secondRow').offsetTop - OFFSET) {
    changeColor('#333', 'gray', '#333', '#333');
  } else {
    changeColor('gray', '#333', '#333', '#333');
  }

})

function fixIfScrolled() {

  if (window.scrollY >= nav.offsetTop) {
    nav.classList.add("stationary");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("stationary");
  }

  if (window.scrollY == nav.offsetTop) {
    nav.classList.add("largerNavbar");

  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("largerNavbar");
  }

}

window.onscroll = function() {
  fixIfScrolled()
};
```

Comment: will the OFFSET be the height of the navbar?

Comment: Yep. and plus some 20px . You can adjust those values to best viewing experience.